# Center text above wrapped, fixed-width items, ignoring container's leftover space

Tags: css, flexbox

We want the layout that's shown below but don't know how to center the "Center here" text like that. Currently, we're centering it according to the width of the parent container. It's appearing too far to the right. In this example, only two items fit on a row, thus leaving empty space to the right of the items. We want the parent container's width to be as per the min width of the child flexbox to center the text above it. The flex box is flex row with wrapping for items that don't fit in. We basically want to ignore that extra space on the right where the item can't fit and set the width of the parent div accordingly

[image]

The blue color represents the flex-box's width.  Here's the tailwind CSS classes that we're currently using:

```
className="flex flex-row overflow-x-hidden  flex-wrap 3xl:flex-shrink 2xl:block 2xl:grid 2xl:grid-cols-3 3xl:grid-cols-3 justify-items-end "
```

Comment: Could you provide some code of your current structure?

Answer (score 1):

Hard no sample code, but here I tried my best, hope it helps

This is my code sample, you can try it :

```css
body{
  padding: 5%;
}

.container{
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
.container-box{
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box-1, .box-2{
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-box">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```